# Changing formula fill step

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I'm trying to make a formula from one sheet (Sheet 2) which calculates the minimum value of a given block of cells in another (Sheet 1). The block is of consistent size.

When I drag the formula down though, it doesn't change the same interval as the size of the block i.e. instead of the resultant cells formulating data from 1-4, 5-8, 9-12, I am getting results for 1-4, 2-5, 3-6

**Edit:**  I'm trying to get each day's minimum value into sheet 2 to the corresponding day. So for Sheet 2 B5 I'm trying `=MIN('Sheet1'!B2:D5)` and when I want to drag the formula down Sheet 2 B6 should fill as `=MIN('Sheet1'!B6:D9)` but is instead filling as `=MIN('Sheet1'!B3:D6)`.  If I could figure this out for just the one column than I could just nest the two columns under the min function seperately, but have had no luck doing that either.

#### Example

[image: Sheet 1 data]

[image: Sheet 2 Data]

**Edit 2**
On the test page Gary's solution works excellent! However, on my real application I don't start analyzing until 132. I adjusted your formula to be `="Sheet1!B"&(132+4*(ROW()-1)) & ":D" & (135+4*(ROW()-1))` but I get a reference error when I enter the `INDIRECT` function.  It looks like  it turned the first function to reference Sheet 1!B200:D203 for some reason. Is it an issue with where on Sheet 2 I enter this or is it something else I'm not understanding? It even lets me put in negative numbers for the reference start to get the numbers down lower, but still gives the `#REF` error.

Comment: **Post your formulas.**

Comment: Sorry Gary, done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say *Sheet1* is like:

[image]

In *Sheet2* cell **B1** enter:

```
="Sheet1!B"&(2+4*(ROW()-1)) & ":D" & (5+4*(ROW()-1))
```

and copy down.  In *Sheet2* cell **A1** enter:

```
=MIN(INDIRECT(B1))
```

and copy down:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

To make the *Sheet2* formula work on any row, use the ***ROWS()*** function rather than the ***ROW()*** function:

Here I am using **D4** rather than **B1**:

[image]

Comment: On the test page this works excellent! However, on my real application there is data before in Sheet 1 (Data I'm analyzing starts at cell B132 instead of B2). I adjusted your formula to be `="Sheet1!B"&(132+4*(ROW()-1)) & ":D" & (135+4*(ROW()-1))` but I get a reference error when I enter the `INDIRECT` function.  It looks like  it turned the first function to reference Sheet 1!B200:D203 for some reason. Is it an issue with where on Sheet 2 I enter this or is it something else I'm not understanding?

Comment: @astongt615  This formula is designed to work in row # **1** of *Sheet2* ...............where is your formula located??

Comment: On Sheet two the formula is Starting at cell N4

Comment: @astongt615  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: you rock. I think I was having some trouble because I was Checking the changes on both the test page and the actual page at the same time. Rookie mistake. Thanks for your patience and help!

Comment: @astongt615  Thanks for the feedback!