# Excel keep rangee difference when copying

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Excel, having

```
A1 =B11
A2 =B21
```

How to copy paste this formula to a whole rangee from `A1` to `A100`, keeping the ten cells distance delta for each following A value (`A91 =B911` etc)?

When I try to copy both lines, I have only correct delta between two by two lines, not all the lines together..., the third line is not OK:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a direct reference.

```
=INDIRECT("B"&ROW()*10+1)
```

Copied down, that gives you what you're looking for in this instance. If you need this solution for a more complicated sheet than your example, I would still recommend some variation on the `INDIRECT()` function.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: thank you. this is a good workaround. What I was saying is that, Excel gets the point that  there is a gap between A1 and A2 when I copy-paste it bellow, but is not so smart to apply this gap to the A3 cell directly.... it applies only to A4 vs A3, not also to A3 vs A2...

Comment: FWIW, your issue and this solution are similar to [another question](https://superuser.com/q/987566/348859)

Answer (score 1):

This avoids the volatility of INDIRECT():

```
=INDEX(B:B,(ROW($ZZ1)-1)*10+11)
```

the `(ROW($ZZ1)-1)` is just a counter that starts at `0` no matter where it is placed in the worksheet.

`*10` is the pattern desired.

`+11` is the starting row.